# I can not consume my API REST on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, cloud

I did a REST API, I did with Spring Boot. I put the API in Heroku, but when I try to consume this API in Postman it returns me that the credentials are wrong, and when it's time to get in the browser an alert is opened asking for a username and password.

When I squeeze my interface on a local server pointing to the base in Heroku everything works as it should.

Has anyone ever experienced this? is some configuration that I have to set as publish.

Thank you all for the attention.

Comment: I remember seeing this one time but I just refreshed it and everything worked for me - as for the credentials, the default username is "user" or "username" and the password is pasted on the boot logs when you start your Spring boot app.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I did not find the password in the application log.
I'm researching more about it.

Comment: Look for a field like this: "Using default security password: <UUID>"

Comment: This field does not exist in application log. Do you know if I can find this user and password in Heroku page, or I can find only in log?

Comment: Should be in the log - I'm not familiar with the Heroku but I'm sure Heroku has a way to view the terminal logs when your app has booted. If you don't care about this security right now, you could just disable it until you implement security later. Add this to you .properties (security.basic.enabled=false) or .yml (security
  basic:
    enabled: false) file.

Comment: My friend thanks for taking the time to help me. I just realized that the mistake was completely mine. I could not disable basic security because I'm using Oauth2. based on that I went through the Procfile documentation, and I saw that it had a wrong parameter. was **-Dspring.profiles.active = prod but the run was -Dspring.profiles.active = oauth-security, prod**. :)